# HOW TO MAKE IF AND SEARCH STATEMENT GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, search, filter

So i have dropdown (cells J23) and when the dropdown gets the number, i want to show the results number (which is percent cell).
I was use filter, search and if function.

When i was run the if function, it's work. But when i was combine it, it doesn't work.

Here's my function

```
=filter(F10:G,search(J23,IF(J23 < 10, J23, IF(J23 = 10, 10, IF(J23 > 10, J23))), F10:F))
```

If you need my excel, you can access my [google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vO8BiwHYtT6mGRI-SNrZ2YZ0X-LG-ke0mF62qvNaLms/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spreadsheet goal is hard to understand from your current formula. I *think* that you want the following...

In K21:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J21,F6:G8,2,FALSE))`

In K23:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J23,F10:G,2,FALSE))`

Comment: Great. Please take a moment to mark the answer post "Best Answer." This will let the contributor community here know that this issue is solved, and it will make it easier for future site visitors to find this answer. Thanks.

Comment: can you help me again with cells I9? i want to filter by name (cell I6) with number i was input at yellow cell (J6). My function like this

=IF(I6 <> "", filter(A5:C,search(I6,A5:A),search(IF(J6 = 80, 80, IF(J6 = "80/90", "80/90", IF(J6 = 90, 90))),B5:B)), "Please input search box")

Comment: Please mark the post as "Best Answer," since it fully answers what you originally asked. Usually a new question would require a new post. However, I will take a look once you've closed the post by marking the current answer as "Best Answer."

Comment: how to make best answer anyway?

Comment: already! i was new to use this

Comment: done! i'll wait for your help

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A5:C), "where 9=9 "&
 IF(I6="",," and lower(Col1) contains '"&LOWER(I6)&"'")&
 IF(J6="",," and lower(Col2) contains '"&LOWER(J6)&"'")&
 IF(K6="",," and lower(Col3) contains '"&LOWER(K6)&"'")), "no match"))
```

Comment: can u give me example of col1 col2?

Comment: @TIFANYSUSANTO see green cell: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1awtotG-27IPQujEQmBoCc79mWwwha0R7FOHT8iA_S28/edit#gid=0